# Syntax error when casting string to int

Tags: python, string, int

My code:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    result = 0
    s = str(n)
    for c in s:
        result += (int)c    # invalid syntax??????????
    return result

print digit_sum(1234)
```

Result:

```
    result += (int)c    # invalid syntax??????????
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The function is supposed to return the sum of each digit of the argument "n".
Why do I get `SyntaxError` in the commented line? The variable `c` is of type `str`ing so it shouldn´t be an issue to apply a type cast to `int`.

Comment: In Python you **do not cast that way**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python you **do not cast that way**. You use:

```
result += int(c)
```

Technically speaking *this is not casting*: you **call the [`int(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) builtin function** which takes as input the string and produces its equivalent as `int`. You do not cast in Python since it is a dynamically typed language.

Note that it is of course possible that **`c` contains text that is not an integer**. Like `'the number fifteen whohaa'`. Of course `int(..)` cannot make sense out of that. In that case it will raise a `ValueError`. You can use `try`-`except` to handle these:

```
try:
    result += int(c)
except ValueError:
    # ... (do something to handle the error)
    pass
```

Comment: This can also throw an exception if  `c` can't be converted into an integer. It will throw a `ValueError`exception so if possible treat it with a try-except.

Comment: @Gugas: that is indeed a good suggestion. I've added that tho the answer.

Comment: sorry but it's an `except` not a `catch` to pair with the try.

Comment: @Gugas: yeah, some brainfreeze (or being buzzy with too many things at once). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you cast a string to an integer by using a function `int()`.

```
    result += int(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def digit_sum(n):
        numsum=[]
        add_up=str(n)
    for n in add_up[0: len(add_up)]:
        numsum.append(int(n))
    return sum(numsum)
print digit_sum(1234)
```

Basically, you need to cast string to integer using `int(n)`